# No database selected PHP login

Tags: php, mysql, sql, authentication

Im trying to create a Login but everytime I type my credentials and click on Login, I get "No database selected"
Here is my PHP code

```
<?php define('DB_HOST', 'localhost'); 
define('DB_NAME', 'phplogin'); 
define('DB_USER','adminuser'); 
define('DB_PASSWORD','adminuser'); 
$con=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER, "")
//$mysql_select_db = 'phplogin'
//or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error()); 
//$db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con) 
or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error()); 
$ID = $_POST['user']; $Password = $_POST['pass']; 

 function SignIn() 
{ session_start();
 if(!empty($_POST['user'])) 
 { $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM phplogin where userName = '$_POST[user]' AND pass = '$_POST[pass]'") or die(mysql_error()); $row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error()); if(!empty($row['userName']) AND !empty($row['pass'])) 
 { $_SESSION['userName'] = $row['pass']; echo "SUCCESSFULLY LOGIN TO USER PROFILE PAGE..."; } else { echo "SORRY... YOU ENTERD WRONG ID AND PASSWORD... PLEASE RETRY..."; } } } if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { SignIn(); } ?>
```

Where is the mistake?

Kind regards
newbie

Comment: Mistake is `No database selected`. Isn't it clear? And second - throw away `mysql` extension. It's not available in php7.

Comment: what is your php version?

Comment: Mysql not available in php7. You can use mysqli or pdo.

Comment: You have an sql injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to pass the variable $con as the link parameter.

```
mysql_select_db('database', $con) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Where do I have to paste this?

Comment: just remove comment $db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con)

Comment: Now I get
"syntax error, unexpected 'mysql_select_db'"



<?php define('DB_HOST', 'localhost'); 
define('DB_NAME', 'phplogin'); 
define('DB_USER','adminuser'); 
define('DB_PASSWORD','adminuser'); 
$con=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER, "")
mysql_select_db('phplogin', $con) or die(mysql_error());
$ID = $_POST['user']; $Password = $_POST['pass']; 

Is this right like that?

Comment: just follow this link- https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/472821/PHPplusMySQLplusLoginplusForm

Comment: From where does he get the email and password?

Answer (score 0):

Use pdo for prevent sql injection.

**You mistake this**

```
mysql_select_db('database', $con) or die(mysql_error());
```

**`Mysql` not available in php7. You can use mysqli or pdo.**

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=myDB", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully"; 
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would really recommend you to use classes, methods and most importantly **PDOs**.

The use of "unescaped" mysqli is very insecure and vulnerable due to SQL injections.

Also, when storing passwords into your DB, hash them using the PHP function `password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)`; This will generate a hash string that you can store in your DB.

That SignIn with the use of PDO and `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` *to verify the password* would look the following:

**Class DataBase (DB)** (db.php)

```
class DB {
    private $error;
    private $db;
    function Conn()
    {
        try {
            $this->db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=phplogin;', 'adminuser', 'adminuser'); //second adminuser is password
            return $this->db; //Returns PDO object
        }
        catch(PDOException $ex){
            return $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

**Your login.php** (login.php)

```
require_once('db.php');
$db = new DB(); //Create instance of DB class
$conn = $db->Conn(); //Call Conn() method of DB class

$username = $_POST["user"];
$password = $_POST["pass"];

$statement = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM phplogin where userName = :user");
$statement->execute(array(":user"=>$username)); //For :user in SQL query it enters the username you entered in the login form (bind param)
$row = $statement->fetch(); //Returns the row from DB

//password_verify() checks if the password you've enteres matches the hash in the DB
//$row["pass"] is the hash you get returned from the SQL query aboth
if(password_verify($password, $row["pass"])){
   return true; //Or echo "success"
}
else{
   return false; //Or echo "Wrong username/password"
}
```

I hope I was able to help you :)

Comment: And where do I have to paste this things?
I work with a index.html Sir

Comment: Copy/Paste is always a solution. But you have to understand what's going on. I would really recommend you to read into PDOs, classes and methods. There are many great tutorials you can find.
For the db.php you need to create a new file `db.php`. To keep it simply just put it in the same folder as your index.html. Then create a second file `login.php` where you paste the second code.
At your html form put `<form method="post" action="login.php">`. This will call the login.php file when you press the "login" button.

Comment: Yes you are right, thank you Sir.
Then I have a general question: Often I saw tutorials where people said, that their ".php" file is the login for something. But in Xampp (Apache) i cant put an .php file as login file. I just can "index.html" and then localhost can execute this file but he cant execute a ".php" file if I execute "localhost" on the browser. Is there a possibility that if I type localhost, that an ."php" file will be shown or not?

Comment: You mean, that you can't execute .php files on your localhost?